# Текстовый редактор Intellij IDEA 2020.1 выдает ошибки, которых по факту нет

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Месяц не занимался проектом, теперь запустил виртуальную машину с Ubuntu, и получаю такую картину:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Везде, где это возможно и невозможно редактор видит ошибки так, как это было бы при неправильной настройке SDK, однако проект компилируется и запускается. Игнорируя ошибки можно написать какой-то код и он запустится.

Такое происходит на всех, в том числе и свежеиспеченных проектах.

Java SDK 11.0.5, Intellij IDEA 2020.1 Community Edition, OS Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, VirtualBox 6.0.14

Переустановка IDEA не помогла.

Comment: Посмотрите `File->Project Structure->Problems`, там должна быть указана ошибка

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий пустое окно.
Ошибки видит только редактор, компилятору все нравится.

Answer (score 2):

2 варианта:

1. Подпорченный кэш IDEA, лечится через *invalidate cache*
2. Баг самой IDEA, похожие баги уже были - [например](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-71782) - если п. 1 не помогает советую выставить issue в [багтрекере](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) - либо закидают г***м, либо помогут :)